# how to synchronize source code with Enterprise Architect model?

Tags: java, architecture, uml, enterprise-architect, tool-uml

I have a relatively big Java project. I am learning EA to see if it can help me with the code structure refactoring. I have generated the class diagrams with its reverse engineering feature. But I cannot find a way to synchronize the EA model with the changed code, such as new files are added, old files are deleted. I have looked at the similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795706/enterprise-architect-synchronize-with-code?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974836/enterprise-architect-how-to-synchronize-with-source-code-source-model-when) but none helps.

If I import again from the top level, all files are duplicated then. Old files cannot be deleted automatically by EA. And EA failed to add the new files with the Synchronize with Code feature.

My version is 11. anybody can help?

Comment: 11 had quite some flaws. The current version is 13, so yours is a bit out of date.

Comment: Try updating to 13 and see if the problem persists, the process is free as long as you have a license [link](http://www.sparxsystems.com/support/faq/update.html)

Comment: I don’t think the reverse engineering has changed much since 8 or 9, probably before that, but there’s always a chance that they might have changed something more recently. In the import source directory dialogue there is an option to synchronise existing classes, have you got that selected?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the comments, upgrade to the latest version. If the problem still persists then contact Sparx Support by sending in a [bug report](http://sparxsystems.com/support/forms/bug_report.html) and provide them with a reproducible sample.